# validate forms with js mutually exclusive

Tags: javascript, validation

Hi I have almost finished a assignment on "Javascript" although I cant find any information on how to make some fields mutually exclusive, basically the top part of my form the user has to insert the address into mandatory fields then further down the form the is a radio check box the user must pick home address or other, (home being the top address they already inserted) the form is already validated to if the choose the home they do not have to insert any thing in other but I need to make it mutually exclusive so if they choose other it cant be the same as above, can any one please help me or give me a link for a tutorial, cause I can only find info on mutually exclusive radio button or check boxes nothing on what the user inputs to text box thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Joes Fruit and Vegetable Store</title>
<script>
                                                                    //calender dropdown menu 
var monthtext=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
function populatedropdown(dayfield, monthfield, yearfield){
var today=new Date()
var dayfield=document.getElementById(dayfield)
var monthfield=document.getElementById(monthfield)
var yearfield=document.getElementById(yearfield)
for (var i=0; i<31; i++)
dayfield.options[i]=new Option(i, i+1)
dayfield.options[today.getDate()]=new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(), true, true) //select today's day
for (var m=0; m<12; m++)
monthfield.options[m]=new Option(monthtext[m], monthtext[m])
monthfield.options[today.getMonth()]=new Option(monthtext[today.getMonth()], monthtext[today.getMonth()], true, true) //select today's month
var thisyear=today.getFullYear()
for (var y=0; y<20; y++){
yearfield.options[y]=new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
thisyear+=1
}
yearfield.options[0]=new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true) //select today's year
}
                                                                // function validate
 function validate_form ()
{
                                                                //validate name
    valid = true;
                if ( document.input.name.value == "")
        {
                alert ( "Please enter your name");
                valid = false;
        }
                                                                // validate address
                if ( document.input.address.value == "")
        {
                alert ( "Please enter your Address" );
                valid = false;
        }                                                       
                                                                // validate Town
                if ( document.input.town.value == "")
        {
                alert ( "Please enter your Town" );
                valid = false;
        } 
                                                            // validate postcode        
        var y = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
       if(isNaN(y)||y.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
       {
          alert("Postcode must be in numbers.");
          document.getElementById("postcode").focus();
          return false;
       }
       if (y.length>4 || y.length<4)
       {
            alert("Postcode should be 4 digit");
            document.getElementById("postcode").focus();
            return false;
       }  
                                                                // validate home phone
 var y = document.getElementById('hphone').value;
       if(isNaN(y)||y.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
       {
          alert("Home Phone number must be in numbers.");
          document.getElementById('hphone').focus();
          return false;
       }
       if (y.length>10 || y.length<10)
       {
            alert("Home Phone number should be 10 digit");
            document.getElementById('hphone').focus();
            return false;
       } 
                                                                // validate work phone
        var y = document.getElementById('wphone').value;
       if(isNaN(y)||y.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
       {
          alert("work Phone number must be in numbers.");
          document.getElementById('wphone').focus();
          return false;
       }
       if (y.length>10 || y.length<10)
       {
            alert("Work Phone number should be 10 digit");
            document.getElementById('wphone').focus();
            return false;
       }
                                                                // validate fax
        var y = document.getElementById('fax').value;
       if(isNaN(y)||y.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
       {
          alert("Fax number must be in numbers.");
          document.getElementById('fax').focus();
          return false;
       }
       if (y.length>10 || y.length<10)
       {
            alert("Fax Phone number should be 10 digit");
            document.getElementById('fax').focus();
            return false;
       }
                                                                // validate email   
        {
        var x=document.forms["input"]["email"].value;
        var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
         var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
         if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
         {
         alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
        }
        } 
                                                                // validate radio buttons
 var o = document.getElementById('rad1');
 var t = document.getElementById('rad2');
if ( (o.checked == false ) && (t.checked == true ) )
 {
                                                                // validate alternative address
                        if ( document.input.street.value == "")
        {
                alert ( "Please enter alternative Address" );
                valid = false;
        }                                                       
                                                                // validate  alternative suburb town
                if ( document.input.suburb.value == "")
        {
                alert ( "Please enter alternative Suburb or town" );
                valid = false;
        }
            }                                           // validate alternative postcode    
        if ( (o.checked == false ) && (t.checked == true ) )
 {                                          
       var y = document.getElementById('postcode2').value;
       if(isNaN(y)||y.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
       {
          alert("Alternative Postcode must be in numbers.");
          document.getElementById('postcode2').focus();
          return false;
       }
       if (y.length>4 || y.length<4)
       {
            alert("Alternative Postcode should be 4 digit");
            document.getElementById('postcode2').focus();
            return false;
       }  
   }
                                                            //validate message box
        var o = document.getElementById("card");
        if (o.checked == true )
        {
            if ( document.input.message.value == "" ||    document.input.message.value == "Please Enter message here"   )       
            {
                alert ( "Please enter message" );
                valid = false;                                                  
        }
        return valid;
        }                                                                                           
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<b>Order form for Joe's Fruit Shop</b><br>
<br>
<b> * means you must fill in the details.</b><br>
<br>
<b>Your details:</b><br>
<br>
                                                                            <!-- Beggining of Form -->

<form name="input" action="Joes.html" onsubmit="return validate_form ()">
                                                                            <!--name input form -->
     * Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="Enter your Name"><br>
    <br>
                                                                            <!-- Address input form -->
     * Address: <input type="text" name="address" id="address" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="Enter your street address"><br>
    <br>
                                                                            <!-- Town & state dropdown form-->
     * Suburb or Town: <input type="text" name="town" id="town" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="Town"> * State:
                                                                            <!-- state drop down list -->
    <select name="state">
        <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="QLD">QLD</option>
        <option value="SA">SA</option>
        <option value="WA">WA</option>
        <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
        <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
        <option value="NT">NT</option>
        <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
    </select>
                                                                            <!-- post code input form -->

     * Postcode: <input type='text' name="postcode" id="postcode" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="****"><br>
    <br>
                                                                            <!-- Home phone input form-->

     * Phone: <input type='text' name="hphone" id="hphone" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="x-xxxx-xxx">
                                                                            <!-- work phone input form -->

     * Work phone <input type='text' name="wphone" id="wphone" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="x-xxxx-xxx"><br>
    <br>
                                                                            <!-- Fax input form-->

     *Fax: <input type='text' name="fax" id="fax" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="0x-xxxx-xxx">
                                                                            <!-- Email input form-->

     * Email address: <input type='text' name="email" id="email" onclick="this.value='';" onsubmit="return validateForm();" placeholder="Enter your current email"><br>
    <br>
    <br>
                                                                            <!-- credit card form -->   <b>Credit card details:</b><br>
    <br>
     * Type:
    <select name="credit card">
        <option selected="selected" value="AMEX">Amex</option>
        <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
        <option value="Mastercard">Mastercard</option>
    </select>
                                                                            <!--credit card month expiry date-->
     *Expiry date:
    <select name="expiration_month">
        <option value="">Choose...</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">Febuary</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
                                                                            <!-- Credit card year expiry date-->
    <select name="expiration_year">
        <option value="">Choose...</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <b>Purchase details</b><br>
    <br>
                                                                            <!-- Product dropdown form-->
     * Product:
    <select name="product">
        <option value="carrot">Bag of carrots</option>
        <option value="zucchini">Zucchini</option>
        <option value="cabbage">Cabbage</option>
        <option value="grapes">Grapes</option>
        <option value="tomatoes">TAS</option>
        <option value="apples">Apples</option>
        <option value="banana">banana</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="cucumber">Cucumber</option>
    </select>
                                                                        <!-- Quantity dropdown form-->
     Quantity:
    <select name="quantity">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
     * <b>Deliver to:</b>
    <br>
    <br>
                                                                        <!-- Address Radio check buttons-->
    <input type='radio' id="rad1" name='rad' checked="checked">Home Address<br>
    <input type='radio' id="rad2" name='rad'/>Other Address<br>
    <br>
                                                                        <!-- alternative street form-->

     Street <input type='text' name="street" id="street" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="Street"><br>
    <br>
                                                                        <!-- alternative Suburb form-->

     Suburb <input type='text' name="suburb" id="suburb" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="Suburb or town"><br>
    <br>
                                                                        <!-- alternative State dropdown form-->
     State
    <select name="state">
        <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="QLD">QLD</option>
        <option value="SA">SA</option>
        <option value="WA">WA</option>
        <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
        <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
        <option value="NT">NT</option>
        <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
                                                                        <!-- alternative post code form -->

     Postcode:<input type='text' name="postcode2" id="postcode2" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="****"><br>
    <br>
    <br>
     * Date delivery required: 
    <!-- Calender drop down menu-->
    <select id="daydropdown">
    </select>
    <select id="monthdropdown">
    </select>
    <select id="yeardropdown">
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//populatedropdown(id_of_day_select, id_of_month_select, id_of_year_select)
window.onload=function(){
populatedropdown("daydropdown", "monthdropdown", "yeardropdown")
}
    </script>
    <br>
    <br>
                                                                        <!-- include a card option-->
     Include a card: <input type="checkbox" name="card" id="card">Yes<br>
    <br>
     Personal message on card: <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="20" rows="10" onclick="this.value='';">Please Enter message here</textarea><br>
    <br>
     Click on <b>Submit</b> when done; click on <b> Clear form</b> to reset. 
                                                                        <!-- submit button-->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                                                                        <!-- reset button-->
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form><br>
<script>
<!--
document.write("<i>Last updated "+document.lastModified+"<I>");
//-->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you write the validation code above? Because if you did (and understand how it works), this should not be difficult at all. You already have code that checks if a field was entered, and you already have conditionals using more than a single input field.

Comment: Hi yes I wrote it but I have had a lot of help with it, its still very confusing for me but as I go it starts making sense, my course basically just directed us at the w3c web site for our learning materials I was thinking some thing like                  if (address.value == '' && street.value == '')
   {
    alert ( "Enter different street");   
         return false
     }                                                          But it don't work

Comment: I tryed this too but no luck                                        if(street.value.match(address))
 {
  alert (" enter different address")
  return true; 
 }

Answer (score 0):

This is incomplete. I've added functions for some of your options. copy and check for yourself where the changes are. I think you can do the rest

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Joes Fruit and Vegetable Store</title>
<script>
                                                                    //calender dropdown menu 
var monthtext=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
function populatedropdown(dayfield, monthfield, yearfield){
var today=new Date()
var dayfield=document.getElementById(dayfield)
var monthfield=document.getElementById(monthfield)
var yearfield=document.getElementById(yearfield)
for (var i=0; i<31; i++)
dayfield.options[i]=new Option(i, i+1)
dayfield.options[today.getDate()]=new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(), true, true) //select today's day
for (var m=0; m<12; m++)
monthfield.options[m]=new Option(monthtext[m], monthtext[m])
monthfield.options[today.getMonth()]=new Option(monthtext[today.getMonth()], monthtext[today.getMonth()], true, true) //select today's month
var thisyear=today.getFullYear()
for (var y=0; y<20; y++){
yearfield.options[y]=new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
thisyear+=1
}
yearfield.options[0]=new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true) //select today's year
}
                                                                // function validate
 function validate_form ()
{
                                                                //validate name
    valid = true;
                if ( document.input.name.value == "")
        {
                alert ( "Please enter your name");
                valid = false;
        }
                                                                // validate address
                if ( document.input.address.value == "")
        {
                alert ( "Please enter your Address" );
                valid = false;
        }                                                       
                                                                // validate Town
                if ( document.input.town.value == "")
        {
                alert ( "Please enter your Town" );
                valid = false;
        } 
                                                            // validate postcode        
        var y = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
       if(isNaN(y)||y.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
       {
          alert("Postcode must be in numbers.");
          document.getElementById("postcode").focus();
          return false;
       }
       if (y.length>4 || y.length<4)
       {
            alert("Postcode should be 4 digit");
            document.getElementById("postcode").focus();
            return false;
       }  
                                                                // validate home phone
 var y = document.getElementById('hphone').value;
       if(isNaN(y)||y.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
       {
          alert("Home Phone number must be in numbers.");
          document.getElementById('hphone').focus();
          return false;
       }
       if (y.length>10 || y.length<10)
       {
            alert("Home Phone number should be 10 digit");
            document.getElementById('hphone').focus();
            return false;
       } 
                                                                // validate work phone
        var y = document.getElementById('wphone').value;
       if(isNaN(y)||y.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
       {
          alert("work Phone number must be in numbers.");
          document.getElementById('wphone').focus();
          return false;
       }
       if (y.length>10 || y.length<10)
       {
            alert("Work Phone number should be 10 digit");
            document.getElementById('wphone').focus();
            return false;
       }
                                                                // validate fax
        var y = document.getElementById('fax').value;
       if(isNaN(y)||y.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
       {
          alert("Fax number must be in numbers.");
          document.getElementById('fax').focus();
          return false;
       }
       if (y.length>10 || y.length<10)
       {
            alert("Fax Phone number should be 10 digit");
            document.getElementById('fax').focus();
            return false;
       }
                                                                // validate email   
        {
        var x=document.forms["input"]["email"].value;
        var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
         var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
         if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
         {
         alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
        }
        } 
                                                                // validate radio buttons
 var o = document.getElementById('rad1');
 var t = document.getElementById('rad2');
if ( (o.checked == false ) && (t.checked == true ) )
 {
                                                                // validate alternative address
                        if ( document.input.street.value == "")
        {
                alert ( "Please enter alternative Address" );
                valid = false;
        }                                                       
                                                                // validate  alternative suburb town
                if ( document.input.suburb.value == "")
        {
                alert ( "Please enter alternative Suburb or town" );
                valid = false;
        }
            }                                           // validate alternative postcode    
        if ( (o.checked == false ) && (t.checked == true ) )
 {                                          
       var y = document.getElementById('postcode2').value;
       if(isNaN(y)||y.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
       {
          alert("Alternative Postcode must be in numbers.");
          document.getElementById('postcode2').focus();
          return false;
       }
       if (y.length>4 || y.length<4)
       {
            alert("Alternative Postcode should be 4 digit");
            document.getElementById('postcode2').focus();
            return false;
       }  
   }
                                                            //validate message box
        var o = document.getElementById("card");
        if (o.checked == true )
        {
            if ( document.input.message.value == "" ||    document.input.message.value == "Please Enter message here"   )       
            {
                alert ( "Please enter message" );
                valid = false;                                                  
        }
        return valid;
        }                                                                                           
}
function fnc1()
{
    document.getElementById("hsuburb").value=document.getElementById("town").value;
    document.getElementById("hstate").value=document.getElementById("state").value;
    document.getElementById("postcode2").value=document.getElementById("postcode").value;
    document.getElementById("hsuburb").disabled="disabled";
    document.getElementById("hstate").disabled="disabled";
    document.getElementById("postcode2").disabled="disabled";

}
function fnc2(myid)
{
    value=document.getElementById(myid).value;
    a=document.getElementById("town").value;
    b=document.getElementById("state").value;
    c=document.getElementById("postcode").value;
    if(value==a)
    {alert("change your town");
    document.getElementById(myid).value='';
    }
    else if(value==b)
    {alert("change your state");
    document.getElementById("default").selected="Selected";
    }
    else if(value==c)
    {alert("change your postcode");
    document.getElementById(myid).value='';
    }

}
function fnc3()
{
    document.getElementById("hsuburb").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("hstate").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("postcode2").disabled=false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<b>Order form for Joe's Fruit Shop</b><br>
<br>
<b> * means you must fill in the details.</b><br>
<br>
<b>Your details:</b><br>
<br>
                                                                            <!-- Beggining of Form -->

<form name="input" action="Joes.html" onsubmit="return validate_form ()">
                                                                            <!--name input form -->
     * Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="Enter your Name"><br>
    <br>
                                                                            <!-- Address input form -->
     * Address: <input type="text" name="address" id="address" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="Enter your street address"><br>
    <br>
                                                                            <!-- Town & state dropdown form-->
     * Suburb or Town: <input type="text" name="town" id="town" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="Town"> * State:
                                                                            <!-- state drop down list -->
    <select name="state" id="state" >
        <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="QLD">QLD</option>
        <option value="SA">SA</option>
        <option value="WA">WA</option>
        <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
        <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
        <option value="NT">NT</option>
        <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
    </select>
                                                                            <!-- post code input form -->

     * Postcode: <input type='text' name="postcode" id="postcode" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="****"><br>
    <br>
                                                                            <!-- Home phone input form-->

     * Phone: <input type='text' name="hphone" id="hphone" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="x-xxxx-xxx">
                                                                            <!-- work phone input form -->

     * Work phone <input type='text' name="wphone" id="wphone" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="x-xxxx-xxx"><br>
    <br>
                                                                            <!-- Fax input form-->

     *Fax: <input type='text' name="fax" id="fax" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="0x-xxxx-xxx">
                                                                            <!-- Email input form-->

     * Email address: <input type='text' name="email" id="email" onclick="this.value='';" onsubmit="return validateForm();" placeholder="Enter your current email"><br>
    <br>
    <br>
                                                                            <!-- credit card form -->   <b>Credit card details:</b><br>
    <br>
     * Type:
    <select name="credit card">
        <option selected="selected" value="AMEX">Amex</option>
        <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
        <option value="Mastercard">Mastercard</option>
    </select>
                                                                            <!--credit card month expiry date-->
     *Expiry date:
    <select name="expiration_month">
        <option value="">Choose...</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">Febuary</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
                                                                            <!-- Credit card year expiry date-->
    <select name="expiration_year">
        <option value="">Choose...</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <b>Purchase details</b><br>
    <br>
                                                                            <!-- Product dropdown form-->
     * Product:
    <select name="product">
        <option value="carrot">Bag of carrots</option>
        <option value="zucchini">Zucchini</option>
        <option value="cabbage">Cabbage</option>
        <option value="grapes">Grapes</option>
        <option value="tomatoes">TAS</option>
        <option value="apples">Apples</option>
        <option value="banana">banana</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="cucumber">Cucumber</option>
    </select>
                                                                        <!-- Quantity dropdown form-->
     Quantity:
    <select name="quantity">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
     * <b>Deliver to:</b>
    <br>
    <br>
                                                                        <!-- Address Radio check buttons-->
    <input type='radio' id="rad1" name='rad' onClick="fnc1()">Home Address<br>
    <input type='radio' id="rad2" name='rad' onClick="fnc3()" />Other Address<br>
    <br>
                                                                        <!-- alternative street form-->

     Street <input type='text' name="street" id="hstreet" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="Street"><br>
    <br>
                                                                        <!-- alternative Suburb form-->

     Suburb <input type='text' name="suburb" id="hsuburb" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="Suburb or town" onChange="fnc2(this.id)"><br>
    <br>
                                                                        <!-- alternative State dropdown form-->
     State
    <select name="state" id="hstate" onChange="fnc2(this.id)">
        <option value="-1" id="default">select</option>
        <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="QLD">QLD</option>
        <option value="SA">SA</option>
        <option value="WA">WA</option>
        <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
        <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
        <option value="NT">NT</option>
        <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
                                                                        <!-- alternative post code form -->

     Postcode:<input type='text' name="postcode2" id="postcode2" onclick="this.value='';" placeholder="****" onChange="fnc2(this.id)"><br>
    <br>
    <br>
     * Date delivery required: 
    <!-- Calender drop down menu-->
    <select id="daydropdown">
    </select>
    <select id="monthdropdown">
    </select>
    <select id="yeardropdown">
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//populatedropdown(id_of_day_select, id_of_month_select, id_of_year_select)
window.onload=function(){
populatedropdown("daydropdown", "monthdropdown", "yeardropdown")
}
    </script>
    <br>
    <br>
                                                                        <!-- include a card option-->
     Include a card: <input type="checkbox" name="card" id="card">Yes<br>
    <br>
     Personal message on card: <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="20" rows="10" onclick="this.value='';">Please Enter message here</textarea><br>
    <br>
     Click on <b>Submit</b> when done; click on <b> Clear form</b> to reset. 
                                                                        <!-- submit button-->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                                                                        <!-- reset button-->
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form><br>
<script>
<!--
document.write("<i>Last updated "+document.lastModified+"<I>");
//-->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey sorry for late reply got caught up with my son, thanks for your time I will check it out now

Comment: Sounds great. Still you have to update code. I've just given you the layout